# Counting the number of tags in a single post - data explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, dataexplorer

I am trying to write a query that will count the number of tags under a single post. I somehow cannot wrap my head around splitting up the tags in a single row and counting those tags.

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) suggest creating a function to split the tags up, but you can't create functions on data exchange.

Here is the query that I have so far, which will just give me the posts that are in both Posts and Tags.

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Title, p.Tags, t.TagName
FROM Posts as p 
INNER JOIN Tags as t ON p.Id = t.Id
```

Comment: Show please the tables' structure.

Comment: Also some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I think tags are stored as eg(your question): `[<sql><sql-server><tsql><split><dataexplorer>]` So you can get the tags count by `LEN(Tage)` - `LEN(REPLACE(< or > FROM Tag))`

Comment: mel, If I get this correctly, the column `Posts.Tags` is a string with a list of tags. If so, you will have to split this into single tokens and use them to join against your `Tags` table (not the `p.Id`). But this is wild guessing... Try to set up a [mcve] with DDL, sample data and expeted output.

Comment: @Shnugo they are using the schema here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks for the pointer, placed an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count number of tags using `Tags` column:

```
SELECT Id, Title, Tags, LEN(Tags) - LEN(REPLACE(Tags, '<','')) AS tag_number
FROM Posts as p 
WHERE Id = 2647
```

**[SEDE Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/954554)**

Comment: This worked well, thank you! How did you know that the tags were delimited with '<'?

Comment: @mel `SELECT TagName
FROM Tags
WHERE TagName LIKE '%<%' OR TagName LIKE '%>%'` -- 0 rows

Answer (score 1):

This is close to guessing, but my magic crystal ball (and Martin Smith) told me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @mokupPosts TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomePost VARCHAR(250),Tags VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO @mokupPosts VALUES
 ('First post','<matlab><plot><ternary><ternplot>')
,('Second post','<powershell><java><python>')
,('Third post','<image><opencv><image-processing>');
```

--The query will return multiple rows per `Post` with each token separately.

```
SELECT p.*
      ,B.token.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') Token
FROM @mokupPosts p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(p.Tags,'><','||'),'<',''),'>',''),'||','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') B(token);
```

You can easily `INNER JOIN` this to your existing table `Tags` on the token directly and perform a grouped `COUNT()`.

If the tags might include forbidden characters (like `&, < and >` and many more), you can use an additional inner `SELECT FOR XML PATH('')` to implicitly escape them:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,B.token.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') Token
FROM @mokupPosts p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(p.Tags,'><','||'),'<',''),'>','') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'||','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') B(token);
```

### UPDATE: Simpler approach

Attention: The tags must not include characters forbidden in element's names like `&, < and >` (and many more)!

This query will return a list of empty elements *as xml* simply by replacing the closing `>` with `/>`. The query then will use `/*` to iterate all of them and return their name via `local-name(.)`:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,B.token.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')AS Token
FROM @mokupPosts p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(p.Tags,'>','/>') AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/*') B(token)
```

The result is the same as above...

### UPDATE 2: I just tried this [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

...and it works :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution! The link in Update 2 is routing me to a new query instead of the one that you wrote. Please let me know when it's fixed so I can see what you did!

Comment: @mel, Just copy my query there and use `Posts` instead of `@mockupPosts`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this I guess

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Title, p.Tags, count(t.TagName)
FROM Posts as p 
INNER JOIN Tags as t ON p.Id = t.Id
group by p.Id, p.Title, p.Tags
```

Comment: That is simply wrong. cause we have 3 tables (Posts, PostTags, Tags). It's a many to many relationship here.

Comment: where did you state that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN to get this as

```
SELECT P.ID,
       P.Title,
       P.Tags,
       COUNT(Tags) TagsCount
FROM Posts P INNER JOIN PostTags PT
       ON P.Id = PT.PostId
WHERE P.ID = 53243136
GROUP BY P.ID,
         P.Title,
         P.Tags;
```

**[SEDE Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/954578/counting-the-number-of-tags-in-a-single-post-data-explorer)**

*UPDATE:*

Here is also another way

```
SELECT P.ID,
       P.Title,
       P.Tags,
       COUNT(TT.Value) - 1 TagsCount
       FROM Posts P CROSS APPLY (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(Tags, '>')) TT
WHERE P.ID = 53243136
GROUP BY P.ID,
         P.Title,
         P.Tags;
```

**[SEDE Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/954686/another-way-too)**